# How to Filter/Disable a Github Workflow by Organization Name?

Tags: github-actions

I set up a [schedule trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule) recently, and it works great. It runs on the default branch exactly the way the documentation specifies. However, it also runs on the default branch of every fork of my repository, which is an undesired side effect.

The current workflow looks like this:

```
name: SonarCloud
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  schedule:
    - cron: '36 12 * * *' # 12:36 PM UTC, daily (picked an odd start time to try to avoid competing for agents with other projects)
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and analyze
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.11
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis
      - name: Cache SonarCloud packages
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~\sonar\cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
      - name: Cache SonarCloud scanner
        id: cache-sonar-scanner
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: .\.sonar\scanner
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar-scanner
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar-scanner
      - name: Install SonarCloud scanner
        if: steps.cache-sonar-scanner.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          New-Item -Path .\.sonar\scanner -ItemType Directory
          dotnet tool update dotnet-sonarscanner --tool-path .\.sonar\scanner
      - name: Build and analyze
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information, if any
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          .\.sonar\scanner\dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"apache_lucenenet" /o:"apache" /d:sonar.login="${{ secrets.SONARCLOUD_TOKEN }}" /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io"
          dotnet build
          .\.sonar\scanner\dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="${{ secrets.SONARCLOUD_TOKEN }}"
```

I have done a dozen or so Google searches, but cannot seem to find the specific syntax I need. **How do I either filter the workflow or conditionally disable the job/tasks so it only runs on 1 specific GitHub organization and doesn't run when someone forks it?**

Comment: Did you try adding and `if` condition to the `build` job? For example: `if: github.repository == '<owner>/<repository>'` ? That way, you would be sure it's the specific organization repo which ran the job.

Comment: @GuiFalourd - Thanks. That is exactly what I found when I finally found the right document. Even though I tried, I couldn't find any document that lists all of the variables below `github.`, which would be easier to find when you know that is what you are looking for than having to go through the quick start.

Comment: I've created some gists to help with that for [push](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/81f41fb8b53a0bd3d63856f919e501c2) and [pull-request](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/e53ec9b6bc783cce184bd1eec263799d) events. You can also simply print the `Github Context` inside the current workflow ([example at different workflow levels](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/24-contexts.yml)).

Comment: @GuiFalourd - Thanks for the tips. I still don't get why they just don't make GitHub Actions more like TeamCity, which simply displays all possible environment variables and their values in the run. Much easier to figure out how to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I guess the 13th search is the charm. I came across the [Quickstart for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/quickstart) which provided a clue - `${{ github.repository }}` (which you have to scroll way down to see what the output looks like in order to confirm that is it).

So, I did a search on that and found [Using conditions to control job execution](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution), which shows the specific example I needed to modify my workflow as follows.

```
name: SonarCloud
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  schedule:
    - cron: '36 12 * * *' # 12:36 PM UTC, daily (picked an odd start time to try to avoid competing for agents with other projects)
jobs:
  if: github.repository == 'apache/lucenenet' # Don't run on forks
  build:
    name: Build and analyze
    runs-on: windows-latest
    
    // Other stuff...
```

Comment: Your attempt to use the if field at the job level is not syntactically correct in GitHub Actions. The if field can only be used at the job or step level, not directly under the jobs key.